# How to combine row data into columns based on unique ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Desired Outcome:

```
TKID    Question        LEVEL
18176    PowerPoint         3
         Excel              3
         Access             3
```

Initial Table

```
TKID    Powerpoint  Excel      Access
18176      3          3          3
```

Essentially, I want to put the question (powerpoint, excel, Access) in a column and the matching skill in a column all still tied to the TKID number.

I was able to do this manually via the offset function but am wondering if there is a vba method as I have hundreds of rows/columns of data. Each TKID has 278 questions that need to be pulled into the question column. Then each TKID repeated.

Comment: Will you always have only 3 categories per TKID, "Powerpoint", "Excel", and "Access"? Or could one ID have like 10 products to look for?

Comment: Also, are the "TKID","Powerpoint","Excel", etc. headers, or does that repeat each time?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for what you're trying?

```
   Sub transposeData()
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, curLastCol As Long, nRow As Long
Dim groupHeaders() As Variant, levels() As Variant
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
Dim tkid    As String

Set mainWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set newWS = Worksheets("Sheet2")
nRow = newWS.Cells(newWS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With mainWS
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
Dim curGroup As Range
Dim i As Long, k As Long

For i = 2 To lastRow         ' using 2, since you have header row
    curLastCol = mainWS.Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Set curGroup = mainWS.Range(mainWS.Cells(i, 1), mainWS.Cells(i, curLastCol))
    tkid = curGroup.Cells(1, 1).Value

    ReDim groupHeaders(1 To curGroup.Columns.Count - 1)
    ReDim levels(1 To curGroup.Columns.Count - 1)
    For k = 1 To curGroup.Columns.Count - 1
        groupHeaders(k) = mainWS.Cells(1, k + 1)
        levels(k) = mainWS.Cells(i, k + 1)
    Next k

    With newWS
        .Cells(nRow + 1, 1).Value = tkid
        For k = LBound(groupHeaders) To UBound(groupHeaders)
            .Cells(nRow + k, 2).Value = groupHeaders(k)
            .Cells(nRow + k, 3).Value = levels(k)
        Next k

    End With
    nRow = newWS.Cells(newWS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Next i

newWS.Activate
copyDownData ("A")

End Sub
Sub copyDownData(Optional ByVal iCol As String)
' This will allow us to quickly copy data down a column.
If IsMissing(iCol) Then
    iCol = InputBox("What column, USING THE LETTER REFERENCE, do you want to copy down?")
End If

Range(Cells(2, iCol), Cells(Rows.Count, iCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Value = Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Value

End Sub
```

Note, I assume your data is laid out like this, on "Sheet1" (change that name as necessary):

[image]

and it will look like this when done:

[image]

Please note that I assume your Sheet2 will have a header row *before* you start the macro.

Comment: If there are 278 rows, the copying columns hard-coded to 2 and 3 will be a problem.

Comment: @Raystafarian good point. I'll update if OP runs into an issue

Comment: @BruceWayne I think that is on the right track, refer to my initial table layout that I have in my question however -- the powerpoint, excel etc. "skills" are listed horizontally with level listed below

Comment: @Codey - *facepalm* I have it backwards (thought the first table was input, second was output) - I'll tweak the code, may be until tomorrow. Sorry, I read it too fast!

Comment: @Codey - Try the new code, I think I got it.

Comment: @BruceWayne That works perfectly! thank you so much! -- any way I can add TKID to copy down with each matching question? I've tried but can't quite master it)

Comment: @Codey - See the edit. I added an extra Sub that will copy the data down.

Comment: I ended up using this! Thank you so much @BruceWayne 
Sub FillDown()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
With Range("A2:A" & LR)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub

Comment: @Codey yeah good call, that will be quicker. In the interest of time I just used the whole column. Since you restrict that range it should run quicker. (If it works, mind marking as the answer to "close" the question?)

Comment: @Codey - did you ever get it working?